# How to convert Java Object to Json formatting attribute name

Tags: java, json

I'm currently working on Rest service migration from RestExpress to Jersey framework where I have to have the same output as RestExpress.

```
public class AnnouncementDTO {

    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String details;
    private String postedBy;

    private String permanent;
    private String dismissible;

    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;

}

ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(announcementDTO );
```

Output:

```
{
  "id" : null,
  "title" : "<font size=\"3\" color=\"red\">This is some text!</font>",
  "details" : "<p>fhmdhd</p>",
  "postedBy" : "Portal, Administrator",
  "permanent" : null,
  "dismissible" : null,
  "startDate" : "Jul 19, 2014, 04:44 AM IST",
  "endDate" : null,
  "read" : null
}
```

My requirement is to format attribute names as **postedBy** to **posted_by**. So expected outcome will be as follows.

```
{
  "title":"<font size=\"3\" color=\"red\">This is some text!</font>",
  "details":"<p>fhmdhd</p>",
  "posted_by":"Portal, Administrator",
  "start_date":"Jul 19, 2014, 04:44 AM ET"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@JsonProperty("posted_by")
private String postedBy;
```

Comment: Thanks this is working. But I was searching for more generic solution since I have few DTO objects

Answer (score 1):

I think you can annotate like

```
@XmlElement(name="posted_by")
private String postedBy;
```

Comment: Thanks this is working. But I was searching for more generic solution since I have few DTO objects

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do so
The first one is

Download Jar from here and add to your class path http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.3.1
and then import com.google.gson.Gson;

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
String s=gson.toJson(Your object);
```

s is your json string.

and the other way is
for this method you will have to add getters and setters to your model class

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

JsonObject jsonObject=new JsonObject();
jsonObject.addProperty("propertyname",announcementDTO.gettermethod1());
jsonObject.addProperty("propertyname",announcementDTO.gettermethod2());
String s =jsonObject.toString();
```

here s will be your final jsonised string.

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Thanks this is working. But I was searching for more generic solution since I have few DTO objects